# How can be identified each child component of the same type rendered by the same parent component

Tags: reactjs, components

I am very new to React, and I cannot figure it out how to differentiate 2 different child components of same type.

In my case, I am trying to build an application that allows comparing the prices over the last 5 years for 2 different car models.

I have 2 SelecComponent's, having as options the car manufacturers in the database, and 2 SelecComponent's where I need to list the available car models in the database for each of the selected car manufacturers, so each of the first 2 SCs should only control one of the 2 SCs having the car models stored.

Normally I would identify the SelecComponent's by different IDs and manipulate them with jQuery, but what would be the best way to do it in React?

Parent Component:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      carProducers: [],
      carModels: [],
      selectedProducer: null,
      selectedModel: null
    }
  }


  //function to retrieve the carmakers in order to initialize the drop down elements in the page
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("/AutoExposed/API/carmakers.php")
    .then(response => {
      var data = response.data
      this.setState({
        carProducers: parseCarProducers(data)
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  //function to retrieve the car models once the car producer has been selected
  carProducerSelected1 = (selectedValue) =>{
    this.setState({selectedProducer: selectedValue}, () =>{
      axios.get("/AutoExposed/API/carmodels_GET.php?carmaker=" + this.state.selectedProducer.value)
      .then(response => {
        var data = response.data
        this.setState({
          carModels: parseCarModels(data)
        }) 
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    })   
  }

  carModelSelected = (selectedValue) => {
    this.setState({selectedModel: selectedValue}, ()=>{
      console.log(`The car model has just been selected: `, this.state.selectedModel.value)
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
              <SelectComponent selectOptions={this.state.carProducers} onOptionSelected={this.carProducerSelected}/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
              <SelectComponent selectOptions={this.state.carProducers} onOptionSelected={this.carProducerSelected}/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">

            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">

            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
            <SelectComponent selectOptions={this.state.carModels} onOptionSelected={this.carModelSelected}/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
              <SelectComponent selectOptions={this.state.carModels} onOptionSelected={this.carModelSelected}/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">

            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
              <ChartComp />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>





      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Child Component:

class SelectComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        selectedOtptionState: null,
    }

```
optionWasSelected = (selectedOption) => {

    this.setState({selectedOtptionState: selectedOption}, () => {
        this.props.onOptionSelected(this.state.selectedOtptionState)
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <Select 
            value={this.state.selectedOtptionState}
            onChange={this.optionWasSelected}
            options = {this.props.selectOptions} 
        /> 

    );
}
```

}
export default SelectComponent;

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data back in an array, then you need to map over it and for each iteration(object) in the array give it a component. and in the component you will pass it the current iterations(spreading in the current item's info to the components props object) information and display it in the component.

`apiData.map(item,index)=>{
      return <CarComponent {...item} key={index}/>})`

now you have all the info on the current cars information passed to props and you can display the information

```
const CarComponet=props => {

      return (
          <div>

            <h1>{props.title} </h1>
              <p>{props.carMake} </p>
              <p>{props.carYear} </p>
              <p>{props.carPrice} </p>
         </div>

             )
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with what you have set up. The difference here is a bit of a shift in thought process - with something like jQuery you would hookup the events to elements based on ID and then update them through the events directly where as with react you hookup the event handlers at render and then update state when events are triggered which then re-renders with the new state;

First - since you have two different cars / producers you will need state variables for each to store the two different values and their models (e.g. `selectedMainProducer`, `selectedCompareProducer`, `mainCarModels`,  `compareCarModels`). Also, in this case it is better to have separate event handlers to differentiate which select is used and set the appropriate state:

```
<SelectComponent onOptionSelected={this.onMainProducerSelected} ... />
...
<SelectComponent onOptionSelected={this.onCompareProducerSelected} ... />
...
```

And then store the two different values and their models in your state, e.g.:

```
onMainProducerSelected = (selectedValue) => {
  this.setState({
    selectedMainProducer: selectedValue,
  },() => {
    axios.get(api + this.state.selectedMainProducer.value).then(response => {
      var data = response.data
      this.setState({
        mainCarModels: parseCarModels(data), // <-- separate models
      });
    });
  });
}

onCompareProducerSelected = (selectedValue) => {
  this.setState({
    selectedCompareProducer: selectedValue,
  },() => {
    axios.get(api + this.state.selectedCompareProducer.value).then(response => {
      var data = response.data
      this.setState({
        compareCarModels: parseCarModels(data), // <-- separate models
      });
    });
  });
}
```

With this, you then render your secondary selects based on your `selectedMainProducer` and `selectedCompareProducer` state.

e.g.

```
<SelectComponent selectOptions={this.state.mainCarModels} ... />
...
<SelectComponent selectOptions={this.state.compareCarModels} ... />
...
```